# Altering Qt Application keyboard events

Tags: events, qt, qt4, keyboard

I'm trying to do the following - given an keypress event in an QT Application, I want to intercept it, modify it (for instance, replacing Qt::Key_Up with 0x81001310), and send it into the app again.

Ideas?

Comment: Does my answer have some problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does overriding the *event* method work? If you do get all of the keypresses there, just consume the events you wish to replace and send new events that you want.

Might not work, just an idea that should be easy to test.

Be careful to not cause infinite recursions or loops :)

Edit:
If this doesn't work, you can always create an eventFilter and modify the events that way. However, if you do this, you might have to install the event filter for many things.